# How to dynamically schedule tasks in Django?

Tags: python, django, celery

I need to build an app in Django that lets the user do some task everyday at the time they specify at runtime.

I have looked at Celery but couldn't​ find anything that will help. I found apply_async and I can get the task to execute once at the specificied duration but not recurrent. I am missing something but don't know what.

Please suggest how can I achieve this.

Comment: Hi Kamal, did you achieve this? If so, please let me know how did you achieve. Thanks in advance. It would be appreciated if you could help me out.

Answer (score 2):

There is `django-celery-beat` package which allows you to dynamicly add tasks to database and then they are executed as you defined in database.(e.g. every 5 minutes) But currently they have bug which causes that task is not appended to celery queue when added to database. One suggested workaround is to restart celery process every time that new task is added. 
I solved it with Dan Baders `schedule` package. I scheduled task on every minute which checks database for tasks that need to be executed in current minute. Then I start each of this tasks in new thread.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Django-Celery-beat seems to be what I am looking for, schedule package also seems promising but I need something integrated with Django. I will check if the bug is fixed .

Comment: I checked last week while I needed exactly the same as you. I can share you code snippet of my solution with schedule package if you need it. Can you mark it as accepted then?

Comment: Yes sure if the solution helps me.

Answer (score 2):

Advanced Python Scheduler might be a solution for you.

https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler

https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

APScheduler can dynamically add jobs.

You can look my github example:
https://github.com/easytrader/Apscheduler_for_django/blob/master/trips/views.py

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution which will prevent using heavy AMQP stack, preventing external dependencies like `Celery`, One thing you can do is that you can write a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#howto-custom-management-commands),

```
python manage.py my_daily_cmd
```

If you are using windows use [cron](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job),
if you are using windows use [at](https://www.lifewire.com/at-command-2618090) or [schtasks.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx),

with cron/at/schtasks.exe, you can run your `my_daily_cmd` at your desired time.

Comment: I need the user to be able to schedule task, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [`django-crontab`](https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab) is a good solution for you.

Comment: Thanks @ikreb but it seems that I will need to hardcode the time in settings.Py, but I need to set them dynamically based on user input.

Comment: Well, maybe then it's not the best solution, but you can run each minute a cronjob who check whether there are user tasks.

Comment: Yes it seems reasonable to check every minute , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Celery and cron is [python-rq](http://python-rq.org/) with [rq-scheduler](https://github.com/ui/rq-scheduler).

Comment: @KamalSingh In my experience it's reliable and involves less setup and choices than setting up Celery :)