# Scheduled Notification in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, cron, push-notification

I have a model in which there is a date and time field and the user detail. i want to send a notification to that user on the specified date and time.

One solution is to use cron jobs that checks for pending tasks after specified time. But the issue is that if I have a notification scheduled for after 1 minute and cron job interval is say one hour, the notification will be sent after 59 minuter of the scheduled time. Moreover if there are no notifications for next 10 days, the cron job will keep on running in the background.

Comment: have you tried take a look into this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43733387/how-to-dynamically-schedule-tasks-in-django

Comment: For simple schedule (without setting up real time db like Redis), you can have a look to the django-q package.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60439489/django-run-tasks-possibly-in-the-far-future

I had the same problem a while back, maybe this is of help

Comment: I have a solution but not sure if that is suitable or implementable. We can set interval of cronjob to be dynamic. Whenever we add a new event, a signal is dispatched. We can then get the datetime of that event and if the difference of that time with current time is less than other event in the db, we can change the interval of cron job to be that time. And when the cron job runs, it again check for the closet event and set the interval to that.